# ado.recordset "losing" fields

Tags: asp-classic, ado, recordset

I'm working on an old classic asp project. The database is structured terribly, each row is well in excess of limits (18 different nvarchar(2000), numerous nvarchar(256), and more...)

I made a small fix which changes the order in which the fields are retrieved from the recordset.

What I am now seeing  has me mystified. Fields that do initially exist disappear as I use other fields.

For Example, I have:

```
if(RS.Fields('field1').value){
   //do something
}
if((RS.Fields('field2').value){
   //do something
}
```

In some of my results, field2 is not showing up when checked (after field1), but if I check immediately before field1, it does exist.

Is this a known behavior? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem was two fold:

One, the order the fields appear in code needed to match up with the order they were in the DB. Yeah, don't know, but it works.

Two, the fields need to be immediately loaded into variables.

```
if(RS.Fields('f1')){
   doWork(RS.Fields('f1'));
}
```

does not work, but

```
var f1 = RS.Fields('f1');

if(f1){
   doWork(f1)
}
```

does.

Comment: Known issue with Access database that was never meant to be used in web  environment in the first place. For the record, the "culprit" is the nvarchar(2000) or any such field with more than 256 length - classic ASP have problem handling such fields.

Comment: Oh my god, I was also unlucky to work on classic asp project and had same problem. Ordering variable assignments in order that they comes in DB solve my issue. WAT??!